# AWS Lambda function with One-Zone EFS and internet access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

My Lambda function was working well until last night when it suddenly lost internet access.

It's connected to a VPC in order to access my One-Zone EFS.

A found out that to have a Lambda function connect to the internet when connected to a VPC, I need to set up one subnet to have access to a Route Table that's set to an NAT gateway.

So far so good.

Now, when I try to add the other (NAT) subnet to my Lambda function, it tells me

`EFS file system  referenced by access point does not have mount targets created in all availability zones the function will execute in. Please create EFS mount targets in availability zones where the function has a corresponding subnet provided.`

So I tried to add the EFS to the new subnet as well (despite this not making sense to me since I only ever want to use that for internet access).

Now to the bummer - when trying to add another mount target for the new subnet, EFS tells me `You can only create one mount target per Availability Zone.`.

Do I absolutely have to disable One-Zone for EFS in order to get my tiny Lambda function connected to the internet again?

After reading Mark's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69013543/2161301), I have removed the subnet that I initially added for the EFS and only left the subnet with internet access (that is now also connected to EFS) enabled. Now I don't understand what I created the other routing table for because if I understand correctly, one subnet can only use one routing table and in my understanding the current configuration does not make use of the routing for the EFS but it can for some reason still access it.

Anyway, I'm not gonna touch anything anymore, happy it's running now.

Comment: What do you  mean by "it suddenly lost internet access"? That suggests that either the Lambda function was badly configured to start with (e.g. it was connected to multiple subnets, at least one of which did not have a route to NAT/IGW) or that something changed.

Comment: Hey jarmod, you are probably right. It was basically the n% chance of the lambda using the other subnet. I still don't understand a single thing of what happened but it's working now :)

Comment: Always worth understanding and addressing the root cause, for sure. Things that magically start working will fail again at some point in the future. Glad to hear that it's working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> EFS file system  referenced by access point does not have mount
> targets created in all availability zones the function will execute
> in.

This means that you need to modify the Lambda function so the only VPC subnet(s) it is configured to run in are in the same availability zone as the EFS mount target. It sounds like you have it configured to run in more than one subnet/availability zone currently.

Comment: But do I not have to add both, the subnet for EFS access and the subnet for NAT access? That's what I have read

Comment: A Lambda function can't use more than one subnet at a time. If you add both of those subnets, then half the time you run the function it will have access to the NAT but not EFS, and the other half of the time it will have access to EFS but not the NAT. You should have one subnet configured with access to both, and configure Lambda to run in that subnet.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense - I just had a successful connection with the "bad" config again, now I understand why. I have ticked and edited my answer